# Can't access data from database using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, wpdb

I'm trying to make an AJAX call for the first time in wordpress. I followed some tutorial and have came to this point so far. But when I'm trying to console.log the data I get from database inside my AJAX call, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Code:

functions.php

```
function my_ajax_handler(){
    global $wpdb;
    $name = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM username");

        echo $name;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_call_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_call_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );

function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style("child-style", get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style("parent-style", "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery", 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_styles");
```

quiz-loged-page.php

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: { 'action': 'call_my_ajax_handler' }
}).done(function() {
  console.log(data);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass data as an argument in `done(function(data)` funtion.

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: { 'action': 'call_my_ajax_handler' }
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. The only problem that I have now is that it returns Array0 in console.log, but I want it to return string. My database has only names of strings. Do you know how I can do that? Now I just select `*`, but putting a string doesn't help.